# How to test if an instance method was called inside a function using Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

As part of my unit tests (using pytest), I would like to check that the method "my_method" below is called.

```
def f():
    my_instance = MyClass()
    my_instance.my_method()
```

I there any way I can do this ?

Comment: You can add an instance variable to `MyClass`, which would initially be `False` and set it's value to `True` inside `my_method()` so that whenever it is called, you know it

Comment: `patch()` the method with a Mock and check if it was called.

Comment: But how can I access this instance variable outside the scope of the function f as my_instance is only defined inside f ?

Comment: You just have to check that `my_method` is called on an instance of `MyClass`. You patch `MyClass.my_method`.

Comment: Klaus D., MrBean Bremen, thank you ! I ended up with a working solution that I am going to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a working solution using 'patch' from the 'mock' module as suggested in the comments of my question.

*my_file.py*

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def my_method(self):
        pass

def function():
    my_instance = MyClass()
    my_instance.my_method()
```

*test_my_file.py*

```
import mock

from my_file import function

@mock.patch('my_file.MyClass.my_method')
def test_function(mock_method):
    function()
    mock_method.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: What about without mocking `MyClass.my_method` away? If we want to check it was called, but it should still execute the logic.

Comment: Do you possibly know what if I have two instances and I would like to check them individually in a single unit test?

Answer (score 0):

recommended change is:

```py
def f(cls):
    cls.my_method()

my_instance = MyClass()
f(my_instance)
```

Then you can mock `my_instance` and check if it was called.

Comment: I would prefer not to change current implementation for testing purpose if possible

Comment: It's natural to change the code for testing. It means the code has a problem if your code was difficult to test.